# vsjitdebugger.exe suggests a new instances, ignoring the one already running - what to do?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010

I am debugging two instances of the same process (run with different command line arguments).
Let us refer to them as agents.

Now while debugging the first instance I am starting the second one. I must add that Image Execution Flags define that the agent be started through a debugger, which is vsjitdebugger.exe.

Now, my hope was that vsjitdebugger.exe will allow me to attach the already running VS2010 instance to the new process, however, it only suggests to open a new instance.

I think this has to do with the fact that the current VS2010 instance is already debugging a process, but I do not understand why it matters. After all, from within VS2010 it is no problem to attach to more than one process.

Does anyone know how to make vsjitdebugger.exe recognize the open VS2010 instance, even if the latter is already attached to a process?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch back to VS and use Tools + Attach to Process.  Click No on the JIT debugger prompt :)

Comment: How is that possible?  The main thread of the program won't start running until after you dismiss the JIT dialog.  Attach first, *then* click No.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. Let me test it.